# Turning On General Query Logging FOR WINDOWS in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to view the actual SQL resulting from a php call to mysqli->prepare, and apparently the only way to do that is by logging all queries.  However, I can't seem to manage to turn on query logging in mysql for windows.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

All you do is put:

```
log=query_log_file_name
```

In your `my.ini`. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html